# How to find out if the Windows are still bootable?

Tags: dual-boot

Back in the days I installed both Ubuntu & Windows on two separate partitions of my SSD. Then I stopped using computers for a few years. I forgot a lot. After I pulled my PC back out of storage I turned it on and my Ubuntu 16.04 started. I didn't get an option of choosing OS while booting. I didn't even remember there is Windows installed alongside Ubuntu. I updated Ubuntu to 20.04 and then I found there is still a partition on my SSD containing Windows. Can I still possibly boot up into this Windows anyhow?

Comment: Depending on if this is an older BIOS computer, or a newer UEFI computer, shortly after power on, you can hold down the SHIFT key, or ESC key, (timing of the key press is somewhat critical here), and that will get you to the GRUB menu where you can select which OS to boot to. If that doesn't work, you may have to firmware boot by holding down the F10 or F12 function key (key varies by manufacturer) at the firmware splash screen and select the OS there.

Answer (score 1):

To check windows is still there and boot from it go to `Boot-options` by pressing Esc or any other key when your power on your laptop

If windows is working then fix your boot by [boot-repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you!

BIOS is useless when both OSes are on the same disk.

boot-repair helped. It restored GRUB menu which allowed me to try to boot into the Windows.

(Windows don't work anymore due to inaccessible_boot_device error.)